# Process32FirstW returns ERROR_BAD_LENGTH

Tags: delphi, winapi

I would like to use `Process32FirstW` but I get `ERROR_BAD_LENGTH` when I call `GetLastError`.  Using `tlhelp32` seems to work but I would like to know what I do wrong here:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows;

type
  PROCESSENTRY32W = record
    dwSize: Cardinal;
    cntUsage: Cardinal;
    th32ProcessID: Cardinal;       // this process
    th32DefaultHeapID: Pointer;
    th32ModuleID: Cardinal;        // associated exe
    cntThreads: Cardinal;
    th32ParentProcessID: Cardinal; // this process's parent process
    pcPriClassBase: Longint;    // Base priority of process's threads
    dwFlags: Cardinal;
    szExeFile: array[0..MAX_PATH - 1] of WideChar;// Path
  end;

function Process32NextW           (hSnapshot: Cardinal; var lppe: PROCESSENTRY32W): LongBool; external 'kernel32';
function Process32FirstW          (hSnapshot: Cardinal; var lppe: PROCESSENTRY32W): LongBool; external 'kernel32';
function CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (dwFlags, th32ProcessID: Cardinal): Cardinal; external 'kernel32';

function GetParentPID : Cardinal;
var
  HandleSnapShot    : Cardinal;
  EntryParentProc   : PROCESSENTRY32W;
  CurrentProcessId  : Cardinal;
begin
  result          := 0;
  HandleSnapShot  := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot($00000002, 0);
  if HandleSnapShot <> Cardinal(-1) then begin
    EntryParentProc.dwSize := SizeOf(PROCESSENTRY32W);
    if Process32FirstW(HandleSnapShot, EntryParentProc) then begin
      CurrentProcessId := GetCurrentProcessId;
      repeat
        if EntryParentProc.th32ProcessID = CurrentProcessId then begin
          result := EntryParentProc.th32ParentProcessID;
          break;
        end;
      until not Process32NextW(HandleSnapShot, EntryParentProc);
    end else begin
      writeln(GetLastError);
    end;
    CloseHandle(HandleSnapShot);
  end;
end;

begin
  writeln (GetParentPID);
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Does `SizeOf(PROCESSENTRY32W)` match that of `tlhelp32`?

Comment: Also, I don't see `stdcall` in your kernel32 external declarations.

Comment: @RomanR. that's what it was. Thank you. Sorry about that.

Comment: @RomanR. If you could please provide this as an answer. I'm sorry for deleting it.

Comment: All the prototypes you're defining here has Delphi (at least since Delphi 7) in the `TlHelp32.pas` unit. Also, you're defining them wrong. Windows native types are already defined and I'd suggest you to use them (`HANDLE <> Cardinal` -> `THandle`, `DWORD <> Cardinal` -> `DWORD`, `BOOL <> LongBool` -> `BOOL` etc.).

Comment: @TLama I just used these native vars to match the record size.

Comment: @whosrdaddy, possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591841/process32firstw-returns-error-bad-length#comment27362086_18591841 :-)

Comment: @Tlama: lol, didn't see that :) Apparently it was already stated in the question...

Comment: @Tlama: double-lol, I overlooked that in question :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> function Process32NextW           (hSnapshot: Cardinal; var lppe: PROCESSENTRY32W): LongBool; **stdcall;** external 'kernel32';

You omitted `stdcall;`. Calling convention is important, and having this word lost, your code is calling API incorrectly getting you unpredictable result. So, you have to be 
careful there.

Comment: I'll try to be careful next time and make sure that API calls have the `stdcall`. Thank you very much for your answer.